# iPhone Simulator not working directly in Visual Studio Code - How to resolve?

Tags: flutter

VSCode lacks direct iPhone simulator integration. Developers typically use Xcode for iOS development, running simulators separately, as VSCode primarily focuses on code editing.
but somehow can i open simulator directly by vscode for using flutter

i except some good answer

Comment: unfortunately you need to install Xcode to create a iPhone simulator even if you edit in Vscode, You will need Xcode all the time for different functions when developing your flutter app so it best to install it. a nice command is open -a simulator to see your available simulator to run on